# Publishing Communities - taking excessively long

Tags: community, publisher

This week (since my upgrade to Spring '20), I feel that publishing my community (production & sandbox) has been taking about 10x the amount of time that it normally does.  I am having to wait about 15 minutes for a publish.  Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: Are you using [ExperienceBundle](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_developers_exp.htm)?

Comment: I am not.  Just trying to make a basic typo change in a rich content component on the website takes about 15 minutes to publish.  What would I gain by using ExperienceBundle regarding the slow publishing problem?

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question! I thought you were referring to moving communities between orgs as opposed to simply publishing a change in a single org. I noticed no difference in my Spring 20 org with publishing a change in communities (took about a minute). I think, if you can, Salesforce support is your best option.

Comment: Thanks - I logged a case with Salesforce.

Comment: I see your case resulted in a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YoafQAC&title=spring-20-publishing-in-experience-community-builder-takes-more-than-10-minutes). Sharing to provide visibility